# Accessing User's specific data ASPX / .MDF table

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, mdf

I am using Visual studio and have the following page_load function on my Default.aspx web form:

```
if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            //Display all records on the form load
            DisplayCars("");
```

I have a user, where I can get their username (which I have used to add as the "Creator" of the specific data record). I want to use this username to only display cars where the username = ACar.Creator

How would I go about doing this? I have everything setup in order to do this.

I need something like the following:

```
if (User.Identity.Name == ACar.Creator) {
show this record
}
```

But I do not know the syntax for this within aspx/sql

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should actually do this in the database by passing username

```
public DataTable GetUserRecord(string userName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string to database");

    using(conn)
    {
    string sql = "SELECT car.CarName, car.Model FROM car WHERE car.Creator = @UserName";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

    dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

From your page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   DataTable dt = GetUserRecord(User.Identity.Name);
   if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      string firstRowCarName = dt.Rows[0]["CarName"];
      //etc
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, the logic behind this seems good. But what is DataTable? I assumed it was a table function that would be recognised but I don't know it.